# attributes are not being saved in session

Tags: java, servlets, session-variables, session-cookies, sessionid

I have a webapp and it works exactly fine in my local environment but when i deploy it to other app server there is something going wrong in session part.

In one servlet I store session attribute as

```
session.setAttribute("customer", customerObj)
```

In other servlet I get the this attribute as

```
session = request.getSession();
Customer customer = (Customer) session.getAttribute("customer")
```

and i see that customer is null. When i check jSessionId for each request the Ids are same. What causes this problem? Is there any posibility that there may be a configuration difference between the appServers?

Thanks

session-descriptor in weblogic.xml is like this

```
<session-descriptor>
        <session-param>
            <param-name>CookiesEnabled</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </session-param>

        <session-param>
            <param-name>TrackingEnabled</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </session-param>

        <session-param>
            <param-name>CookieDomain</param-name>
            <param-value>.blabla.com.</param-value>
        </session-param>

        <session-param>
            <param-name>CookieComment</param-name>
            <param-value>Blabla Session Tracking Cookie</param-value>
        </session-param>

        <session-param>
            <param-name>CookieName</param-name>
            <param-value>BSession</param-value>
        </session-param>

        <session-param>
            <param-name>IDLength</param-name>
            <param-value>10</param-value>
        </session-param>

        <session-param>
            <param-name>CookieMaxAgeSecs</param-name>
            <param-value>-1</param-value>
        </session-param>

        <session-param>
            <param-name>PersistentStoreCookieName</param-name>
            <param-value>WLCOOKIE</param-value>
        </session-param>

        <session-param>
            <param-name>PersistentStoreType</param-name>
            <param-value>memory</param-value>
        </session-param>

        <session-param>
            <param-name>URLRewritingEnabled</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </session-param>

        <session-param>
            <param-name>InvalidationIntervalSecs</param-name>
            <param-value>60</param-value>
        </session-param>
        <session-param>
            <param-name>TimeoutSecs</param-name>
            <param-value>540</param-value>
        </session-param>

    </session-descriptor>
```

Comment: Is `Customer` serializable.

Comment: Is the other app server just a single machine or a load balancer with several machines behind?

Comment: @Henry exactly, the first thing that came to my mind, but the OP says that the jSessionId for each request is same. So, it doesn't look like that.

Comment: Are you sure that customerObj is not null? Is it possible that "customer" is being overwritten by something else, somewhere?

Comment: @TJ- yes guys. I wrote "And no there is no load balancer" at the end of post but then I deleted it because I saw I mentioned jsessionId issue before :). So is there any other opinion. I am getting really crazy :( Still couldnt find a solution. The customerObj I set is not null btw. I didnt even override the customer in session. The funny thing is it is working in my local environment.

Comment: @MoritzPetersen yes it is serializable.

Comment: This code looks okay. You may try using [ session = request.getSession(true); ] in both read and write. Or paste some more relevant code (web.xml etc.) so that someone is able to help you out. Do other attributes persist in the session? What stays what goes?

Comment: @TJ- All attributes are lost in other request but the session is the same session instance. I will update my question with session descriptor tags.

Comment: @TJ-Before that line I have this

HttpSession session = request.getSession();

Comment: how you are printing out jSessionId? can you print out request.getSession().getId() in both and see if they are same?

Comment: `<session-param>
            <param-name>CookieDomain</param-name>
            <param-value>.blabla.com.</param-value>
        </session-param>`  how you are accessing the second server ? is this configuration preventing your code from creating a cookie.

Comment: @Subin no problem with creating cookie and with sessionId.

Comment: Are you using WebLogic on both local and deployment environments?

Comment: @Med Yes I am using weblogic on both environments. I am curious about proxyserver if it is caching my request response.